# Visual Studio word highlighting plugin

Tags: visual-studio, ide

Are there any free plugins for Visual Studio (2005 & 2008) that highlight all words in the current document that match a highlighted word?  This feature is in Notepad++ and Eclipse, but strangly not in VS.

I've tried the free version of CodeRush Express for c#, but it only works for c#. I would like the plugin to work regardless of the type of code I'm writing (c#, JavaScript, C++)

I've also tried RockScroll, but I only want the highlighting feature.

Thanks

Comment: Find all references in VS doesn't help you?

Comment: BTW: A highlight all references will be built into VS 2010 it seems:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434901

Comment: Find all references works, but takes a few mouse clicks and still doesn't highlight the matches

Answer (score 2):

[Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com) has this.

It also has many other features that make it well worth its price. You can download a trial and check it out. Be warned, though: I have yet to see someone who had the trial used for a week and didn't ask management to buy it. Just by asking it for me to work with, I already have infected three shops with it...

Answer (score 1):

Visual Assist may have this feature

it is not free but you can try evaluation..

Answer (score 0):

Wordlight is an addin for VS2008 with such functionality. Check it
http://code.google.com/p/wordlight/

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

http://download.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=highlighterr&DownloadId=192795&FileTime=129383558978930000&Build=17831